# Custom page numbering does not affect whole document

Tags: page-numbering, page

I have a problem with page numbering. Till now I have just only seven pages of my document, but just only one has the desired page numbering. The rest of pages has different.

[image: right page numbering]

[image: wrong page numbering]

As @Bernard says in the comment below I'm attaching the working example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=35mm,
    right=15mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Strona ~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    Some text \dots
    \todo[inline]{example of useage}
    Some text \dots
    \todototoc
    \listoftodos
    \newpage
    Some text \dots

\end{document}
```

The first page with the example of text has right page numbering, but page which is generated automatically, in this example by using `\todonotes` package, has not formatted page numbering. I would like to have page numbering formatted on all pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example, and explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome! If you don't know what a Minimal Working Example (MWE) is check this: (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @Bernard thank you for the answer, I edited my question putting example working code. And of course Welcome :)

Comment: Thanks for editing the question; now it's actually answerable (+1) and someone will likely answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, most `\listof...` macros use `\thispagestyle{plain}` explicitly or by loading `\chapter*` which applz that call of plain style.

By saying `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` this style is redefined to do nothing and the last style set (`fancy` here) still persists.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    left=35mm,
    right=15mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\rfoot{Strona ~\thepage~}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    Some text \dots
    \todo[inline]{example of useage}
    Some text \dots
    \todototoc
    \listoftodos
    \newpage
    Some text \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! I thought so that this will be something easy. I'm starting to writing my engineering thesis, getting help that quickly, is really fancy :) For sure I will have more questions. Once again thank you.

Comment: @EmilKob: Thanks. What does `strona` mean? Is that 'page' in Polish?

Comment: Yes, I'm from Poland, 'strona' means Page :)

Comment: @Emil Kob: Welcome to TeX.SE. Thanks for explanation, I like to learn words from other countries.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, so *Página* in Portuguese.

Comment: @Sigur: Thanks, that was familiar to me already ;-)